# While the chrome version and installed version are same still getting this exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chromer.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();


Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 109.0.5414.74 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Current browser version is 109.0.5414.74 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-T9IGBHU9', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Comment: Select the code and press CTRL+K to format it. Also, add a description of the problem

Comment: Check your chromedriver.exe version again, it seems old.

Comment: Error message clearly mentioned you have old chrome driver installed. `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the version of ChromeDriver is not compatible with the version of Chrome that you have installed. Click on the three dots on the right top -> settings -> about chrome. check the version and you can download the compatible version of chrome driver from the following link: "https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads"